# working xterm.js demo for Svelte/Sveltkit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, xtermjs

High I'm new to Svelte/Sveltkit and I'm trying to get this `xterm.js` demo to work.

https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/wiki/Contributing#running-the-demo

Has anybody had any luck with this. I can see there's a thread the discusses this here https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/s0tasf/how_to_use_xtermjs_with_sveltekit_vite_error_when/however it doesn't seem to be a complete example.

Also, there's a REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/49e256b936604e9ab94e357930891130?version=3.49.0 but that also seems to be incomplete.

Would love to get this working in Svelte.